# Can I use A2 (420x594 mm)size paper format for a score if absolutely needed?

Tags: orchestra, band

My arrangement for the piece "Alpha" by C418 has a lot of instruments, because I'm combining Band and Orchestra in that score. It has a total of 30 staves. I read that staff heights/sizes can not be lower than 7.00 mm. But when I set the sizes to 7.00 mm, there are like 8 staves that are not in the paper. The paper was A4, but when I set it to A2, everything is fine.

Comment: A2 is very large, did you try A3?

Comment: See [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/109978/2600) for some material how to merge different instruments into fewer staves. Completeness and usability of the score have to be carefully balanced.

Comment: FYI for those of you who haven't learned metric yet :). A2 is 16.5 by 23.4 inches

Comment: What do you mean by "can"? What concrete issues are you concerned with? There is not any governmental agency that will fine you for printing music onto an unapproved paper size.

Comment: What about preparing part books for the orchestra and a keyboard reduction for the conductor?

Answer (score 4):

Do you intend to print a conducting score for actual performance? Then practical concerns come in. There are plenty of "study scores" with much smaller print. See [Standard staff size](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/61870/78419) for a lot of info but not a total duplicate question. But note some of what's referenced and shared there speaks to orchestral *parts*, not the conductor's score.

Searching for the text quoted there shows many hits around the web similarly focusing on parts, but [this publication by the Major Orchestra Librarians' Association](https://mola-inc.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/files/mola3/MOLA-Guidelines-for-Music-Preparation.pdf), while repeating the "minimum 7 for parts" recommendation, says this about scores (p 5, or 7 of the pdf file):

> The minimum legible staff size for scores is 4 mm (measured from the bottom to the top of each staff), and note heads should be large enough for the conductor to read with ease at the podium.

But it also says

> In North America, conductor scores should be printed on paper at least 9 x 12 inches but no
> larger than 11 x 17 inches. In Europe full scores should be printed at either B4 JIS (257 x 364 mm) or A3
> (297 x 420 mm).

So... there's your official answer, I guess. Mind, there's no Score Police who will come after you if you do otherwise, and there's certainly nothing against printing smaller for study purposes. But if you want something practical for performance, you could try to abide by these suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

No-one has a domestic printer that prints on A2 paper. Just imagine the score! You wouldn't be able to turn a page without it ripping. I suggest you export your A2 document score to PDF keeping the 7 mm staves. But then use Adobe Acrobat to open the PDF and scale the score to fit onto A4 paper. You may find it entirely legible.

In general, your printed score doesn't *need* 7 mm staves. You could take the printed stave size down to 5 mm and it would still be legible.

And parts printed with 7 mm staves look too big somehow (and you may introduce the need for a second sheet, which requires proofreading to choose a page-turn point).

In a part, a 6 mm stave is entirely readable.

Experiment with PDF export and scaling to A4 and you'll find something that works for you. Good on you for attempting an ambitious arrangement!

Comment: A2 is just a tad larger than a broadsheet newspaper. It would be certainly inconvenient to turn pages, but not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *yes, you can* print your score on that paper.  *Should* you?  Probably not.  One significant problem is that most standard music stands are not tall enough to support the score.  The top several inches of the score will flop over the stand and be infuriating to the conductor.  Another problem is that you will have a hard time printing this.  Standard printers in the US print 8.5 inch inch width; specialty printers (much more expensive) can handle widths up to 11 inches.  But this would require a printer capable of printing a page more than 16 inches wide.  It would take some type of a specialty print shop and be rather expensive, perhaps prohibitively so.

One alternative is to simply shrink the staff height down, as others mentioned.  Another is to reduce the space between the staves.  Using some 8va notation or choosing clefs carefully (for instruments who have several choices) may reduce the need for leger lines, which eat up vertical space.  A third alternative is to construct a condensed score.  Instead of each specific instrument getting its own staff, you could have one staff for "flutes and piccolos," one staff for "clarinet choir," on staff for "low brass," and so on.  This is perhaps the worst of the options as it doesn't give the conductor an exact picture of what is going on - but if the score is relatively simple it should work OK.

You should also be sure you are utilizing staves wisely.  Unless there is a great deal of part independence, you can have three trumpet parts share a staff.  Make use of all the features of your notation software, such as layers.

Comment: One more possible problem is that larger paper might be more likely to be noisier on page turns. Related to that, binding gets more expensive and/or time consuming and/or noisier with larger paper sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Elaine Gould, in *Behind Bars*, gives standard sizes for a variety of score types (see p. 483, "Table 2: Rastral Sizes").

For a full score of the kind in question here, the staff height is 3.7mm. Given that at 7.0mm 8 of 30 staves are off an A4 page, they should all fit comfortably on A4 at 3.7mm.

The 7.0mm staff size, according to Gould, is used for "single-stave parts" such as piano music and songs.